# What is the purpose of OR?

Tags: discussion

I'm not questioning its existence, I'm just genuinely curious about what is its purpose.

Is it for anything related to applying mathematics in programming or just mathematics/theory?

I understand it's related to mathematics, but I wanted to be sure of what it was about, in case I ever ask a question there (so that I stay on-topic) especially given the fact they're also the math SE, which make it a bit confusing.

Comment: Since you mentioned "in case I ever ask a question so that I stay on-topic), I suggest checking out the ["What topics can I ask about here?"](https://or.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) page

Comment: guess that page answer my question :D

Comment: See also https://or.meta.stackexchange.com/q/194/38